# Add contact in OpportunityContactRole whenever a new contact relationship is added to AccountContactRole

Tags: apex, trigger, account, contact

I am new to salesforce and I am developing below functionality:

I want to add a contact in OpportunityContactRole when a new contact is added to AccountContactRole.

I have created below code:

```java
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
    if(Trigger.isAfter){
        if (Trigger.isInsert) {
               AddContactRoleHandler.AddOpportunityContactRole(Trigger.new);
        } else if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
               
        } 
    }    
}
```

```java
public class AddContactRoleHandler {
    public static void AddOpportunityContactRole(List<Opportunity> newOpportunities){
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Opportunity oppObj : newOpportunities){
            accountIds.add(oppObj.AccountId);
        }
            
        Map<Id, List<Contact>> mapOfContacts = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
            
        for(Contact conObj : [SELECT Id, AccountId, Name 
                                    FROM Contact 
                                  WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds]){
            // mapOfContacts.put(conObj.AccountId, new List<Contact>());
            if (!mapOfContacts.containsKey(conObj.AccountId)) {
                mapOfContacts.put(conObj.AccountId, new List<Contact>());
            }

            mapOfContacts.get(conObj.AccountId).add(conObj);             
        }
            
        List<OpportunityContactRole> listOfOCR = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
            
        for(Opportunity opp : newOpportunities){
            if(mapOfContacts.containsKey(opp.AccountId) && mapOfContacts.get(opp.AccountId)!= Null)
                for(Contact con : mapOfContacts.get(opp.AccountId)){
                    OpportunityContactRole ocr = new OpportunityContactRole();
                    ocr.ContactId = con.Id;
                    ocr.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
                    ocr.Role = 'Business User';
                    listOfOCR.add(ocr);
                    System.debug('List of OCR: ' + listOfOCR);
                }
            }

            if(!listOfOCR.isEmpty()){
                insert listOfOCR;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: I want to know if the above code is fine as per the functionality?

Comment: @AnkitKamboj You should test your code to determine if it meets your requirements or not. That usually means both writing a Unit Test class (with multiple tests in it) and manually testing it in a sandbox org. I'll say that you shouldn't expect this code to work as-is though. A change to `AccountContactRole` isn't going to cause the trigger for `Opportunity` to run. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You need to be _highly specific_ and provide plenty of details for people to be able to help you out (and help is not a synonym for "do my work for me").

Comment: hi @AnkitKamboj - a few reflections:
1) AccountContactRole has reached End of Support from Salesforce, so I would first of all consider using Account Contact Relationship instead
2) is there a reason you are writing code for this use-case?  It should be easy to solve using flows